# Stream una webcam a multiples espectadores

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy construyendo una web (en symfony) para una academia y uno de los requisitos es que un profesor pueda emitir en directo una clase a multiples alumnos. Estoy viendo que webRTC es la tecnología que se usa para ello, pero no encuentro ningún tutorial completo.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En ingles he encontrado un par de opciones:

- [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)
- [WEB RTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/WebRTC-PeerConnection.html)

En español no hay más que articulos que describen la tecnología o el uso como app a nivel de exploradores.